# how to add a hyper link in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview control and I would like the field Title to be a hyperlink and execute a stored procedure when clicked. Can anyone assist me in this?

Does this code look right?

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hpTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("SelectBook") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Publisher" HeaderText="Publisher" SortExpression="Publisher" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
</Columns>
```

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the SP you are calling?

Comment: the Stored Procedure should open an empty form and fill it with information from the database.

Comment: Is this form going to be on another page or a modal?

Comment: I was going to have it go to another page. What is the best practice for something like this?

Comment: It is really a matter of preference. Some people do not like modals whereas others dont mind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink id="hplink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("columnname")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("columnname")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

On NavigateUrl, you can redirect to any page and on page_load you can call any stored procedure by using SQlCommand Object.

Comment: Saurabh, does the code above look right to call the Sql Command?

Comment: Why are you not using LinkButton inside GridView and Call procedure inside onclick of linkbutton ?

Comment: I kinda wanted the hyperlink to call the Stored Proc... I have never set this up before and am really not too sure.

Comment: Hypeourlink is used to navigate url, you should use link button instead, its better to call stored procedure  ?

Comment: can I use both navigate to the blank form url and the stored proc to fill it with the data?

Comment: Use LinkButton and fill the data on its OnClick()

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, I was confused a little but this article helped me.